# MULE :process input expression

Tags: mule, mule-studio

How can i input the expression value as inbound:http.request=/${rest.path}/SOMETHING/ABCD ..Is there a way to do it in xml.I am able to take the input as defined in the path Annotation.However i want to take the input dynamically using xml and using inbound request

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please use Mule syntax properly and follow question formatting

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by leveraging the [Mule REST Router Module](http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-rest-router/mule/rest-router-config.html)